# Solution for WCF and mustUnderstand in security header

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui, webrequest

I know this has been an issue for years, but I am hoping for a recent solution other than abandoning WCF for Webrequest since none of the questions going back 5-7 years fix the problem.

If one removes the **mustUnderstand** attribute from the SOAP envelope captured in Fiddler, and drop it into SoapUI a response is received.

The WCF/WSDL mustUnderstand=1 setting is rejected by a partner's server beyond my control with a "Generic error occurred" fault. I have not found any recent settings that allow me to control it, and the vendor (Aperia) has no interest in addressing it, even though they included it in all of their documentation.

I've spent a few hours trying to port the https request to a webrequest, and hate to abandon WCF for this.